# How to enable my react frontend to talk to my nextjs backend

Tags: cors, next.js

So my setup is the following i have a react frontend that is running on localhost:3001 and a nextjs backend that is running on localhost:3000. I have a rest endpoint at /api/employee and i am trying to get the data from my frontend with the following code:

```
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/employee/")
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
            })
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setLoaded(true)
                    dispatch(addEmployee(result));
                }
            )
            .catch((error) => {
                setLoaded(true)
                setError("It looks like an Error happend when trying to load the data please reloade the Website and if the Problem persists notify the Administrator.")
                setHasError(true)
            })
```

But every time i try to fetch the data i get a cors error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/employee/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I tried enabling cors on my backend in multiple different ways but none worked.
I tried adding the headers manually with:

```
res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET', 'PUT'])
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

I tried using the NextCors package:

```
await NextCors(req, res, {
        methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
        origin: '*',
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    });
```

Without the cors configuration my file in extjs looks like this:

File: pages/api/employee

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    // i tried to configure cors here

    if (req.method === 'PUT') {
        const feed = await prisma.employee.create({
            data: req.employee,
        })
        res.status(200).json(feed)
    } else if (req.method === 'GET') {
        const feed = await prisma.employee.findMany({});
        res.status(200).json(feed)
    }
    else {
        res.status(404)
    }
}
```

So my question is what do i need to do to correctly configure cors to work with my setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    

    //avoiding CORS error, more here: https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors
    async headers() {
        return [
          {
            // matching all API routes
            source: "/api/:path*",
            headers: [
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
            ]
          }
        ]
    },
}
```

P.S. It's because of localhost, CORS policy is quite strange